# Short story in a White Dwarf Magazine from 90’s

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, warhammer-fantasy, games-workshop

I’m looking for a short story from a White Dwarf Magazine circa 1990’s. It is Warhammer Fantasy based.

I remember two human fighters (mercenaries) travelling and meeting an old man with a child. Oldman was a wizard and was going to kill the child to give everlasting life.

I lost all of my old White Dwarf Magazines moving many years ago and the short story just stuck with me.

Comment: You might check this website. It has all the magazines (covers and indexes of contents) and you might spot the story your looking for. https://index.rpg.net/display-search.phtml?firstsearch=1&key=magazine&match=loose&value=White+Dwarf

Answer (score 4):

*The Magician's Son* by Barrington J. Bayley, from [*White Dwarf #136*](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/White_Dwarf_136_(UK)) (1991).

> "There are ways to become immortal. There are Champions of Chaos that
> live in the realm of the Chaos Powers,  but They are no  longer human.
> You can become a vampire, one of the undead, but that is like a living
> death. No, our friend  wanted to enjoy life forever as a normal human,
> to stay reasonably young indefinitely.  Well, there  is a foul  way
> to  do  this. Every time the  adept begins  to  age, he must sacrifice
> a child and absorb its youth, its life  forces, into his body.  But
> not just any child will do. It must be between six and twelve years of
> age, and the same sex as the recipient. Most important. the operation
> will not work at all unless the child is the magician's own child."
> Mucnchbek's eyes smouldered. That's why Semperphilius was always so
> anxious about the boy. It was his  own life he was protecting!

[image]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a quote from the story along with the magazine cover (which should, hopefully, jog the questioner's memory).

Comment: Note that in the future it would be best if you could explain how the work matches the OP's description though. Whilst the name is the most important aspect, a description makes it into a good answer and really helps.